# Let P be a p-group. Let A be a normal subgroup of order p. Prove that A is contained in the center of P. (Proof check request)

Tags: abstract-algebra

Since the order of $A$ is $p$, the normal subgroup A is cyclic and consequently Abelian. So, for all $a,b \in A \subset G$, we have $ab = ba$. Thus, $A \subset Z(G)$.

Is this proof valid? I see proofs involving the class equation, but wondering if this approach is okay as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  You've shown that $a,b \in A$ commute with each other, but you have not shown that they commute with everything in $G$.

You're going to need the class equation proof for this one.

Comment: Oh, I see now. Thank you for clarifying. I don't understand the class equation too well, and will have to learn it before using it. Thank you for the evaluation.

Comment: The class equation is ubiquitous in group theory.  Make sure you understand the orbit - stabilizer theorem.  The class equation is just an easy corollary from there.

Comment: Okay, cool. Thanks!